# mono gtk# async method in ui thread

Tags: mono, async-await, gtk#

See this example: https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/blob/master/sample/AsyncSample.cs

It uses async/await for UI events. After awaiting the work it checks if it synchronized (is that the correct term?) to the UI thread. In my personal experiments it never didn't, the example would always print "Not in main thread".

Is that correct behaviour? How should we update the UI after awaiting the work?

Comment: What is your `SynchronizationContext.Current` before the `await`?

Comment: @StephenCleary null :p

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest versions? Should be `GLibSynchronizationContext`.

Comment: 2.12.0.0 which looks indeed older than https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/commit/8e07e7d2257b185866dedfda9cbf32b2e00cd3ee (providing that `GlibSynchronizationContext` i think). Is there any stable release with this code?

Comment: I tried with 2.12.22 from Git, but no luck. Will try with 2.99.1 tomorrow, have to package it for Fedora first.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by Stephen Cleary, this is fixed in the most recent version of gtk-sharp (2.99.1).

Comment: Any idea why xamarin is only distributing version 2.12.30?

Comment: AFAIK: GTK# 2.12.X are C# bindings for GTK 2.X. GTK# 2.99.X are C# bindings for GTK 3.X. MonoDevelop only supports GTK 2.0 out of the box with it's GUI Designer (Stetic).